# What's the curve for a simple select query?

Tags: sql

This is a conceptual question.

Hypothetically, when do select * from table_name where the table has 1 million records it takes about 3 secs.

Similarly, when I select 10 million records the time taken is about 30 secs. But I am told the selection of records is not linearly proportional to time. After a certain number, the time required to select records increases exponentially?

Please help me understand how this works?

Comment: Ask for more details from whomever gave you that information.  In general, selecting from a table would be a linear time operation.

Comment: Is it true for a million, or a billion records? If possible, please provide an article link that explains this concept in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere are things that can make one query take longer than the other even simple selects with no where clauses or joins.

First, the time to return the query depends on how busy the network is at the time the query is run. It could also depend on whether there are any locks on the data or how much memory is available.

It also depends on how wide the tables are and in general how many bytes an individual record would have. For instance I would expect that a 10 million record table that only has two columns both ints would return much faster than a million record table that has 50 columns including some large columns epecially if they are things like documents stored as database objects or large fields that have too much text to fit into an ordinary varchar or nvarchar field (in sql server these would be nvarchar(max) or text for instance). I would expect this becasue there is simply less total data to return even though more records.

As you start adding where clauses and joins of course there are many more things that affect performance of an indivuidual query. If you query datbases, you should read a good book on performance tuning for your particular database. There are many things you can do without realizing it that can cause queries to run more slowly than need be. You should learn the techniques that create the queries most likely to be performant.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is different for each database-server. Try to monitor the performance while you fire your queries (what happens to the memory, and CPU?)

Eventually all hardware components have a bottleneck. If you come close to that point the server might 'suffocate'.